# lists.updatelistitems not updating fields but error code is 0x0000000

Tags: sharepoint

I'm trying to update document's metadata by lists web service.

It's only returning

`<Result ID="1,Update" xmlns="<ErrorCode>0x00000000</ErrorCode">http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"><ErrorCode>0x00000000</ErrorCode></Result>`

and not updating any field.

Comment: Have you checked the event logs on the server?